# Proving that every finite group with $|G| = pqr$ for $p,q,r$ distinct primes is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra

Without loss of generality, let $p < q < r$. Using Sylow's theorem, the amount of $r$-Sylow groups is 1 mod $r$ and is a factor of $pq$, so only $1$ and $pq$ are possible. Now the proof states that in the case that there only exists one $r$-Sylow group, it is a normal subgroup. Why?

Comment: The conjugate of an $r$-Sylow subgroup $H$ should be another $r$-Sylow [and in fact you can get all $r$-Sylows in this way; that's part of Sylow's theorems]. But there's only one, so the conjugate has to just be $H$ again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subgroup $H\le G$ is normal iff for all $g\in G$, $g^{-1}Hg=H$.
Let $H\le G$ be a $p$-Sylow group, then for all $g\in G$, $g^{-1}Hg$ is also a $p$-Sylow group.
Therefore, if there is only a single $p$-Sylow group, it is normal.

If, on the other hand, there is more than one $p$-Sylow group, then all $p$-Sylow groups are not normal since they are all conjugate to each other.